# For the OOXML w:hidden element, what is the corresponding User Interface option to set this?

Tags: microsoft-word

The [spec](http://www.schemacentral.com/sc/ooxml/e-w_hidden-2.html) for the OOXML w:hidden element describes it as "Hide Style From User Interface"

In Word 2010, if I create a new style (Paragraph, or Linked), and then in the Home Tab | Styles pane | Style Manager on the Recommend tab, choose "Hide", saving as WordXML (OOXML) and inspecting the style shows it as 'semiHidden'.

My goal: determine the UI way to introduce this w:hidden attribute on a style, e.g.

w:style/w:hidden

(as it is causing problems in an application)

Answer (score 0):

From the description of the hidden style property in the OpenXml API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.stylehidden.aspx

> This element specifies whether this style shall be hidden from any and
>   all user interfaces when this document is loaded by an application. If
>   this element is set, then this style can be used to format content
>   (i.e. any content which references this style shall have its
>   properties as normal), but the style shall be hidden from all user
>   interface associated with that application. [**Note: This setting is
>   typically used to hide styles which are being used internally by an
>   application which should not be used as formatting in a typical case.
>   end note**]
>
> If this element is omitted, then the style shall not be required to be
>   hidden from the user interface.

From the sounds of this information, my bet is it's one of those developer-orientated properties that have no UI equivalent and can be set only through code.